# Desired State Schema Best Practices for continous schema + data upgrades at different on prem locations

Tags: sql-server, schema, upgrade

I am looking however to blogs/articles on people who did the same so that i can reference my work against other people who also went in this direction before / or even a github repo:

---

I have a project with an application that is 20 years old and mainly for 90% deployed at customer sites. Each customer has different versions and each customer has made its own customizations to the database. The desire is to grow to a cloud based system for newer customers as well as a lot of other new desires. The system also has multiple versions "live" e.g. version 34.54 is a live version as well as 41.33 they are all maintained. And so customers on 34.54 will go to 34.55 not 41.34.

The system uses an in house developed kind of migrations system that reads the current version and then only executes the newer sql to be executed for upgrades. This is tens of thousands of line of sql code of which no one who wrote this is still around with hundreds of questions "why".

The targetted system is NetCore EF which obviously has a form of migrations build in.

What I noticed was that in a lot of places it was a hell to know if the actual schema was correct since it requires to run each an every single sql file by hand in SSMS to know if it was executed or not in the correct order. This is because it not only changes schema but also content (and the amount of tables and data is complexer). It takes a long time for root cause analysis to finally figure out that a customer changed a FK himself.

What I started to do was to write something that instead defines a "desired schema" (slowly) that seems to work pretty well for making sure that also existing installations have all correct tables, indexes, foreign keys, constraints, enum table contents, views, stored procedures, primary keys etc etc. Also because this reduces the amount of migrations needed e.g. changing a pk or changing a fk or changing a column etc.

So this can be run over and over again and each time checks if "everything" is ok and if not corrects it.

What i do is roughly do this (skipping some stuff like permanent deletion etc) (while checking if exists). It contains if not exists and also includes deletions if an object was created long in the past and was deleted long in the past.

- first i create all schemas
- second i run the "versions" (so the changes that are needed for a system older than version specified with the piece of sql a la migrations)

Then the non migration stuff that is independent of version and per table defined since it is probably in the end not templateable but specific per table. This reduces the amount of stuff that is in "migrations".

- then i create the tables itself with only 1 column in the definition
- then i drop all FK's for all tables with specifications per table
- then i drop all indexes, etc, drop pk,
- then i check and update each column to be of the correct size, default, null etc (there could be exceptions that are not handled but these are in "versions" above
- then i create PK
- then i create indexes (drop or with table name), constraints etc
- then i fill enum tables by checking each record against its desired value incl translations
- then i create FKS
- then i create views in layers (views that depend on other views later etc)
- then i create stored procedures
- then i perform loading of specific data via delete and update

I am leaving out some parts but most of the above now leads to being able to run this over and over again and making sure the schema and all none customer specific data is always ok and everything that has to go via "migrations" can still work via "versions".

This saves some headaches and issues knowing for sure that the schema is actually the schema since with a lot of issues and bugs coming in we had no idea what the schema was of the specific customer, so we are standardizing but also this no longer needs migration files that are thousands of lines and for every change a new migration

I am aware of some of the objections that one can have against this, such as that it takes longer to write what one wants as well as that checking and creating all of this again when an upgrade needs to take place, takes "time" to run. But I'm exactly looking for a more weighted opinions / blogs etc against this.

One advantage that i now see is that it gives me background on what there actually is in this database since no-one who worked on this is around anymore. So it lets me consciously think about every table, fk, index etc while doing this and documenting each one.

(and still migrations as normal can be used)

Now however:

I am looking however to blogs/articles on people who did the same so that i can reference my work against other people who also went in this direction before and possibly leverage on this.

For instance I run this via C# code that executes the above in layers and have a sql file per table per item. I could however centralize the info ( table, pk, columns, pks, indexes etc) in one definition and let the system figure out the order for maintainability since that would make it easier for developers to maintain these files which starts to smell like something that possibly is already somewhere on e.g. github I stayed however now with SQL pure since that allows a developer the most flexibility and he can copy and paste that code in SSMS to test it. With a definition file this would be harder to test.

Comment: In one sentence, what is your question?

Comment: I am looking for references/best practices to update schema not transactional but state driven.

Comment: Careful, "List of Software" requests are out of scope. You may want to look at [LiquiBase](https://www.liquibase.org/)

Comment: "*but state driven*" - I'm not really sure what you mean by that, maybe you could elaborate in your post? But based on my understanding of your situation, best practice is usually locking down your database or schema (if you want to allow them access to manage other schemas) so that customer's can't change it, and then don't support their changes. There's an infinite number of things to try to plan for otherwise and would be impossible to manage. This is how some ERP systems do it. Aside from that, then you can use an automated tool to do schema migrations.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're re-inventing a state-based deployment tool. I would choose a tool (Microsoft SSDT, RedGate SQL Change Automation) and then get that to work for your project instead.

Both offer ways to do a hybrid approach as you've described (integrating some "migrations" into the otherwise largely state-based approach).

Here are a couple of articles from respected folks in the Microsoft data platform community on the subject:

[Critiquing two different approaches to delivering databases: Migrations vs state](http://workingwithdevs.com/delivering-databases-migrations-vs-state/) by Alex Yates

[State vs Migration for Database Source Control - decide based on one question](https://www.littlekendra.com/2019/01/23/state-vs-migration-for-database-source-control-the-core-question/) by Kendra Little